# How did I get XP for a class I never played in Multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I just noticed that I already have some XP in Multiplayer for a class I never even created a character in and haven't played with at all:

[image]

How did I manage to get those XP and how can I get more of them? Starting at level 1 is pretty painful, it would be nice if I could level up the other classes before starting to play them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some of the store packs give XP bonuses to random character classes, you probably bought an item that gave Engineer experience. I've seen them in the Recruit item packs. IIRC it's +1250XP for a random class.

What happens is item packs have unlocks for each class/species. The Recruit pack has lots of Human class "unlocks" but since you have them unlocked by default, you always get XP instead.

You can't decide when you get them or for what character, but buying lots of item packs will get you some bonus XP.

Comment: As a side note, buying a lot of Recruit Packs early on in multiplayer also helps improve your baseline weapons for all characters.

Answer (score 0):

When you buy the packs they include characters which unlock in these classes, in this case you got a Salarian Engineer that came with 12500 Exp, these can be gotten multiple times if I'm correct, giving you extra exp.